# Gradle not generating Checkstyle HTML Report

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I am using Gradle version Gradle 4.4.1

I have added the following line to `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
```

When I run gradle check it reports a violation and the process stops.  No HTML report is generated.

Please help me out on this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html)

add this task configuration:

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        html.required = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can you please provide the actual URL of the Gradle documentation page from where you provided that snippet?

Comment: no problem! Please accept the answer if it's correct.